# converting ms word document's special characters to html

Tags: encoding

I have word document and following code which is converting doc into html using Apache POI Api.

```
   serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

   serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");

   serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
```

but the numbering i.e 1), a), i) etc. and bullet points characters are not being parsed correctly, I am getting garbage characters like 1? and when I open the html file in the editor I get numbers with unwanted boxes. I have tried a lot but I don't get proper solution of this.

Please help me out in order to get rid of this encoding issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show examples of the output you are getting?

Comment: I have modifed the above code now I am using "ISO-8859-1" instead of "UTF-8",so I am able to get html entity number(&#8203;) for numbering ( a), b) etc..) in document file. but when i try to unescape generated html using StringEscaptUtil and JTidy lib I get "?" in the text.

//converted html
<span class="s8">a&#8203;&nbsp;</span><span class="s3">Customer No or Customer Name</span>

//unescaped html
<span class="s8">a? </span><span class="s3">Customer No or Customer Name</span>

Please let me know if you need more information